# How to programmatically scroll to bottom of a div while using Simplebar js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I am using [Simplebar](http://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/) and angular 1 and I need to scroll to the bottom of a chatbox (div) whenever there is a new message or when you click on the menu item.

Here is my scroll function in my chatController.js

```
//Function to scroll the chatbox to the bottom.
function scrollToBottom(){
    var objDiv = new SimpleBar(document.getElementById('#simple'));
    objDiv.SimpleBar.getScrollElement()

    // These 2 lines of code did the trick when I didn't use Simplebar
    //var objDiv = document.getElementById("simple");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

And here is my html

```
<div id="chatbox">
    <div class="wrapper" data-simplebar id="simple">
        <div class="chatbar">
            <div>
                <p class="left">User</p>
                <p class="right">Admin</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="empty"></div>
        <div class="messages">
            <div ng-repeat="m in messages | filter: {uc_id:userCompany}:true" 
                 ng-hide="userCompany==null" >
                <div class="chat"
                     title="Sent: {{m.timestamp}}"  
                     ng-class="(m.sentByUser ? 'left' : 'right') + ' ' + 
                               (m.sentByUser && $last ? 'unread' : '')" >
                    {{m.message}}
                </div><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm gaining this error:

```
Cannot set property 'SimpleBar' of null
```

I am also using a flexbox layout to keep the messages on the bottom (this also isn't working since simplebar. but i'm taking on 1 problem at the time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
$('body').scrollTop($('body').height());
```

You can replace `body` according to your dom element

Comment: thanks for the help, but this doesn't work. It does not scroll when i replace body with `#chatbox` or `#simple`

Comment: have you tried `$('#simple').scrollTop($('#simple').height());` this

Comment: May be some other dom element have the scroll in your html, verify and use that element in this function

Comment: Alright, I know the proper DOM element to scroll. ( `.simplebar-scroll-content` ) But it scrolls it to the middle, and not to the bottom.

Comment: you can use big static int value for argument like `$('.simplebar-scroll-content').scrollTop(4000);`

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
$("#chatbox .simplebar-content-wrapper").scrollTop($("#chatbox .simplebar-content-wrapper").prop("scrollHeight"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only solution that worked for me

HTML

```
<div id="listing-container" data-simplebar data-simplebar-auto-hide="false">
    <div>data here</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function scrollIt() {
  const scrollElement = 
  document.getElementById('listingcontainer').SimpleBar.getScrollElement();
  scrollElement.scrollTop = 1200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've used `data-simplebar` html attribute to initialize the SimpleBar, then the below code can be used to scroll it:

```js
$('#simple .simplebar-content-wrapper').scrollTop(some_value);
```

The actual scrollable element would have `simplebar-content-wrapper` class, and it would be inside the element that you've added SimpleBar for.
The class `simplebar-content-wrapper` was mentioned in its [documentation](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar#noscript-support) and can be expected to be consistent across versions.

Or if you have cascaded SimpleBars inside this one, try:

```js
$('#simple .simplebar-content-wrapper')[0].scrollTop = some_value;
```

As in 2021, `Element.scrollIntoView()` can be used to automatically scroll scrollable contents to make specific element visible.
To scroll the chatbox to show the last item at the bottom:

```js
$('#chatbox .messages').slice(-1)[0].scrollIntoView({block: "end"});
```

This is documented by [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) and you may want to check its browser compatibility.
I believe it to be no problem giving up some optional user experience of few users that are still using out-dated browsers, for the trade-off of cleaner code and less coding time and it is not me but them that should be "punished" for their ignorance.

Explained:

1. `$('#chatbox .chat')` selects all chat messages inside `chatbox`.
2. `.slice(-1)[0]` picks the last one.
3. `scrollIntoView({block: "end"})` scrolls scrollable contents to make the message visible at the bottom.